# What's this plain text format for line art or binary images used in PDF?

Tags: pdf, binary-image

I've been doing some test exports from InDesign to PDF to see how images are handled and found that binary images, which InDesign calls Line Art in its settings, get stored in some kind of text format. I'm attaching a [sample PDF](https://app.box.com/s/47aig06ags90ow5ozout6gmj023061y4) and the code (note that the image is a single pixel, so it might be invisible until you blow it up).

```
q
1 1.001 3 2.999 re
W n
q
/GS0 gs
0 0 0 rg
2.9996248 0 0 2.9996248 0.9999999 1.0003752 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
Q
```

Comment: What do you want to know? That simply is a content stream as specified in the PDF specification. The operators are related to Postscript, but to understand them you should simply study the PDF specification.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *content stream*: a set of instructions to draw markings on the page, including bitmap images...the trick being that the actual bitmap data is stored elsewhere, and the content stream just instructs Acrobat (or other app) to put those pixels on the page.

You'd see something similar for *any* sort of image, not just 'binary' or line art images. The actual image data is drawn by the line

```
/Im0 Do
```

which is an instruction to draw an image resource named `/Im0` (which is present somewhere else in the PDF, but not shown in your snippet). All the other instructions simply set up a default graphic state, position the image on the page, etc.